# Java spring. Fill an @JoinFormula object with sqlquery

Tags: java, sql

When I use HQLQUERY all work well, but now I need to use sqlquery to make a more complex query. But it does not work

```
 public class Cli_Client implements Serializable {   

     @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumnsOrFormulas({
            @JoinColumnOrFormula(formula=@JoinFormula(value="(SELECT p.id  FROM con_person p WHERE p.id = id_entity limit 1)",referencedColumnName="id")),
        })

    ....
    }
```

I'm trying

```
String query=" SELECT cc.*,cp.* "
                + " FROM cli_client cc INNER JOIN con_person cp ON cc.id_ent

SQLQuery sqlQuery = session.createSQLQuery(query);
            sqlQuery.addEntity(Cli_Client.class);
```

Comment: Is that title supposed to be English?

Comment: Jaja it must be Fill an @JoinFormula object with sqlquery (Sorry for my english level ).

Comment: Can you be more specific about what is failing and what output you are getting? Can you try a simple query to figure out whether the issue is with your SQL or with the java running it? (For example try: 'select * from con_person')

Comment: The problem is that I do not know how to fill that property with sqlquer 
  @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumnsOrFormulas({
    @JoinColumnOrFormula(formula=@JoinFormula(value="(SELECT p.id  FROM con_person p WHERE p.id = id_entity limit 1)",referencedColumnName="id")),
   })
   private Con_Person con_person;      
As I've tried it gives me java.lang.NullPointerException